# Pushbutton + LED + sound on python raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have to achieve the following task:

You have three switches. Each switch is connected to a pin. When the switch is pressed, an LED which is connected to another pin will light up and a song will be played for `X` amount of seconds:

```
import os
import time
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
         os.system('mpg123 -g 100 -q /home/pi/test1.mp3 &')
         GPIO.output(2, False)

   if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 -g 100 -q /home/pi/test2.mp3 &')
        GPIO.output(3, False)

   if (GPIO.input(25)== False):       
        os.system('mpg123 -g 100 -q /home/pi/test3.mp3 &') 
        GPIO.output(4, False)

  sleep(0.1);
```

Connections are as follows:

3V |----------270ohm------------LED----------| Pin2

3V |----------10kohm--------+----pin 23

```
                         -------SW--| GND
```

My question is, how can I switch on the led and play the sound only for x amount of seconds, and switched them back off after countdown is ready. And how can I interrupt, if another button is pressed, to precede.

Comment: Try this on the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Your question is not right. Every application got steps and conditions. Simple app : `Reader(collect data)--->Compare----> Do some output`, so this is basic app, how you thing finished all on single `loop` ?

Comment: Thanks Will, will check it out.

dsgdfg - sorry but i didn;t understand your question. This script will be running in the background upon switching on the pi, so the wihile loop is there so it will be expecting an input